# Text view running on from previous Text view

Tags: swift, swiftui, textview

I'm trying to create a text reader that lets you tap on a sentence to highlight just the sentence. I want each array of a string to be able to run on from the end of the previous sentence, but I am trying to keep them as separate views so I can easily render them with a background color on a tap gesture.

The righthand image is what I have now with my code. The lefthand side is what I'm aiming for, so it will look like the text is running on from each other, but still actually two separate views so they can be rendered differently.

[image]

Here's my code:
(Note: WrappingHStack is an imported package)

```
struct SwiftUIView2: View {
    let text = [
        ["In principio Deus coelum et terram creavit."],
        ["Nunc terra erat inanis et vacua, tenebrae super faciem abyssi, et spiritus Dei ferebatur super aquas."]
    ]

    init() {

    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(text, id: \.self) { paragraph in
                ForEach(paragraph, id: \.self) { line in
                    WrappingHStack(0..<paragraph[0].components(separatedBy: " ").count, id: \.self, spacing: .constant(5)) { index in
                        Text(paragraph[0].components(separatedBy: " ")[index])
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.teal.opacity(0.2))
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 13)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need UIKit for this with AttributedString and the ability to manipulate selection. SwiftUI isn’t capable of doing what you want to do. You don’t need multiple Views you need something more like a text editor. SwiftUI isn’t capable of that right now.